# How to reuse a variable declared by "var" in C#

Tags: c#, linq, var

What I want to implement is something like:

```
switch(flag)
{
    case 1:
          var query=from w in db.someTable
                    select w;
          break;
    case 2:
          query=from w in db.someTable
                    where w.id==someID
                    select w;
          break;
    case default:
          break;
}
```

But it cannot compile correctly. If I add a `var` before the second `query`, it prompts that query has been declared.
Do I have to change the variable name? Such like: `query1 in case1, query2 in case2`, etc.

---

EDITED 1
Thanks for your help. In fact my code is a little bit more complicated than what I posted above. Here is the complete code:

```
List<object> results=new List<object>();
switch (flag)
{
    case 1:
    var query = from w in db.RADIATION
    where w.DATEDT.CompareTo(dateStr) == 0
    && w.LATITUDE.CompareTo(latitude) == 0
    && w.LONGITUDE.CompareTo(longitude) == 0
    orderby w.TIMETM
    select new { w.RADIATION, w.TIMETM };
    break;
    case 2:
    var query = from w in db.TEMPRETURE
    where w.DATEDT.CompareTo(dateStr) == 0
    && w.LATITUDE.CompareTo(latitude) == 0
    && w.LONGITUDE.CompareTo(longitude) == 0
    orderby w.TIMETM
    select new { w.TEMPRETURE, w.TIMETM };
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        var resultItem = new { TEMPRETURE = item.TEMPRETURE, TIME = item.TIMETM };
        results.Add(resultItem);
    }
    break;
    case default:
    break;
}
```

The two queries are for two different tables. So I don't know how to determine the Type T in IQueryable. Also, what I `select` is an anonymous object using `new { PropertyName = propertyValue }`.
Is there anyway if I insist using the same name `query`?

Comment: You have to define the type then declare it before the switch.

Comment: Do you want to use `query` later on after `switch`?

Comment: @tia No, I don't. I know it's seems a little unreasonable but I just want to use the same name `query` because they are all queries for tables.

Comment: why didn't you define a class as your query result? such as:
List<MyClass> results=new List<MyClass>();
then select new MyClass{}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `var` keyword is irrelevant. You can do it like this:

```
switch(flag)
{
    case 1: {
              var query=from w in db.someTable
                    select w;
          }
          break;
    case 2: {
              var query=from w in db.someTable
                    where w.id==someID
                    select w;
          }
          break;
    default:
          break;
}
```

It is correct syntax, but I would suggest you to extract each case to each method instead.

Comment: Cool, just curly braces. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Declaring with `var` lets you shorten the code, but the variable that you declare remains statically typed, and the scope of that variable does not change.

If you need to use a variable outside `switch`, declare it before the `switch` statement, like this:

```
IQueryable<SomeType> query = null;
switch (...) {
    case 1: query = ...; break;
    ...
    default: ...
}
```

Now you can use `query` outside the `switch`.

Note: There are cases where you must use `var` because the type that you assign to it has no name, but in your first case the type has a name, so you do not need to use `var`.

**EDIT :** Your second case, however, does require a `var`, because you are selecting an anonymous type. In situations like that there are several ways around this problem:

- You can declare a named type for the "superset" of columns that you select (i.e. `TIMETM`, `TEMPERATURE`, and `RADIATION`), or
- In .NET 4.0 you can use `IQueryable<dynamic>`. This shifts some of compile-time checking into runtime, but if you have to go this route, it is very convenient.

Comment: thanks for your help. I've edited my question, please give it a read.

Comment: If I understard right, the query projection is different based on the switch? You can't do that. `var` is still compiled to one type, it's just syntactic sugar provided by the compiler when the Type of the variable can be inferred (that's why var = null can't be done since it applies to any object). Your first and second switch select two different anonymous object, hence two different object types. You can't assign both to one variable.

Comment: Thx! Now I understand the `var` a lot better. I'll try the `dynamic` method later.

Answer (score 0):

if it is same table , you can try this:

```
var query=from w in db.someTable select w;
switch(flag)
{
    case 1: 
          break;
    case 2:
          query=query.Where(w.id==someID); 
          break;
    default:
          query=null; //since linq is Delay query, if you don't use the data in query, it will do nothing.
          break;
}
```

Comment: @Jason Because of deferred execution the behavior will appear the same, but the code does not convey that as neatly as the OP's code does.

Comment: set query=null when case default.   :D

Comment: @Tim.Tang If you do, you can't use `var` anymore. It would be the same as @dasblinkenlight answer

Comment: why didn't define a class as your query result? such as: List<MyClass> results=new List<MyClass>(); then results =..... select new MyClass{} ;